# SQL to return array from different tables

Tags: python, sql

I have a database that has [these tables](http://prntscr.com/mpj0iy).

I would like to make an SQL query to return values from the Pupils and Register tables.

It should return it like this:

[[[[ID, Name, Morning_Registration, Afternoon_Registration, Lates_Week, Lates_HT], ...], ...], ...]

So the arrays with arrays here are as follows: house > year > pupil. So there are multiple houses, and within each house their are multiple years, and within each year there are multiple pupils.

Also, the houses should be in alphabetical order, the years should be in ascending order (they are numbers like 9, 10, 11, etc.) and the pupils should be in alphabetical order based on their surname.

The only input for this query will be the Date at which the Morning_Registration and the Afternoon_Registration should be returned, and that date should be the most recent date.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT Pupils.ID, Pupils.Name, Register.Morning_Registration, Register.Afternoon_Registration, Pupils.Lates_Week, Pupils.Lates_HT
FROM Pupils
INNER JOIN Register ON Pupils.ID = Register.ID
WHERE Date = (select max(Date) from Register)
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't return it in the format I desire, and I haven't worked out how to make it return them in the order I require as well. Is this as far as SQL can take me? Do I need to use Python to get it how I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to add `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses to your query?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Thanks, I didn't know `GROUP BY` existed. I tried to find some examples but they're all just counting things rather than producing an array. Could you by any chance help me edit my current SQL statement to produce the output I desire?

Comment: To get good answers, please add data samples into your question for all tables in the query. And desired output.